# How does running really hot affect your laptop?

Tags: laptop, temperature, sony-vaio

I have a Sony VPCF115FM iy (Q720).  I know there was a bios update posted to keep the machine cooler.

Mine regularly runs between 49 C and 63-64 C.

I purchased it several months ago with the hope that the machine would last 3 years.

Should I be concerned?  Is the machine going to last if it regularly runs at these temperatures?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your laptop's specific case, but generally manufacturers like Sony take good care of designing laptops carefully to avoid thermal damage.

Of course, you have to remember that high temperatures will generally lower the machine's lifetime. Besides, most modern machines have auto-protect systems to make sure that the computers shuts down automatically before any damage is caused.

When you say: "at these speeds" what do you mean? If you've overclocked the machine there may be some more risk involved with the temperatures. Also, you should always take good care of running the most updated BIOS version available.

Answer (score 0):

Your temperatures sound normal for a laptop.  Look at [Speccy](http://www.piriform.com/speccy), a program that will give you information about your computer, including temperatures.

My HP laptop had a graphics card that would hit ~90 degrees. IT stopped goign faster than 12-20 fps at that point.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

> Should I be concerned? Is the machine going to last if it regularly runs at these temperatures?

Your temperatures are about average for a laptop - I wouldn't be too worried. My previous laptop would idle at 60-65 and avg at 85 on load - and I used it for about 3 years without any problems before getting it upgraded.

Don't worry!